# Call,Message,Email,URL is store

Tags: iphone

I want to know where log of following is store in iphone:

1. Call Log
2. Message Log
3. Email Log
4. Url Log.

Is there any database created in iphone? if yes then how i Fetch all these log

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no access to call log from iPhone SDK APIs (at least until you jailbrake it). I'm pretty sure the same will be with other logs you need to access as well.

Comment: Thanks for the information.Plz tel me how i access all log through jailbroken and what i need for Jailbroken iphone any downloads etc

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do that. I was never interested in programming jailbroken iPhones.